# How Do I Create a Completely Empty Span (without spaces)?

Tags: html, is-empty

I'm trying to figure out how I can have:

```
    <span contentEditable="true"></span>
```

without any spaces.

Any ideas on how to do this in JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if this is the right way to do this, but it works. You have to set some css properties like display:block, a width and a height value.

```
    <span contentEditable="true" style="width:120px;height:20px;display:block;"></span>
```

Here you can see an example http://jsfiddle.net/NBfpC/